# Update Value on textbox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, textbox

I have a textbox that you can simply go and do

```
element.value = 1;
```

and change the elements value.

There is a platform called etsy that in order to update a text value for an item quantity you need to click on the box and then click outside in order to submit and officially update the value.
How is it possible to update the value?

Comment: the question isn't very clear on details but you're maybe talking about the [blur event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event)

Comment: what do you mean? are you asking how to do that on js or that etsy platform?

Comment: try firing a change event and a blur event

Comment: @diegod  I dont think that blur event is gonna work without getting some focus on the element.

Comment: @ChrisG I want to do it on the etsy platform by using JavaScript. Change and update value.

Comment: @JimMede then as nullptr suggested, try sending both the change event and the blur event. Or maybe add on top the focus event before changing the value and firing the corresponding change event

Comment: @nullptr dispatch event you mean?

Comment: The way i am doing it is

`element.focus();`

Then:

element.value=1;

Then:

`element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`

Then:

`element.blur();`


still don't works...

Comment: could you maybe try `focusout` instead of `blur`? maybe it will change behaviour?

Comment: anyway in my experience when I had to deal with a chrome extension in charge of auto compiling a form, the strategy that worked in that case was doing: `element.dispatchEvent(new Event('click')); /*change value here*/; element.dispatchEvent(new Event('blur'));` ... maybe the click will trigger the check you have there on that page to comply with a human filling the form?

Comment: @diegod you are god as your name says! This worked like a charm. Everything needed to be worked with event dispatched!

Comment: I swear my name was not involving god at all :D I hope it wasn't mistaken like that by other people thinking I was expecting it sounded like that. Anyway I'm glad it worked. OMG I realize now it's a big blasphemy when you compose the sentence.. I think I need to change it right now

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using a responsive UI framework like React to accomplish this. Here is a Codesandbox link demonstrating how to do this: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-torvalds-bnk90p?file=/src/App.js